# Rules set in XML format

Tags: c#, xml, xsd

I want to create an XML file with a set of rules that can be used as an external input to my program. My program then will parse that XML and converts that rule set into code.

The XML format should be one that I can then convert to simple `if` statements.

For example, if I have something like this:

```
<rule variable='email' value='abc@gmail.com'>
    <or>
       <and>
          <condition name=x operator='!=' value=1>
          <condition name=y operator='>' value=5>
       </and>
       <condition name=z operator='=' value='abc'>
    </or>
</rule>
```

I will translate to C# like this:

```
if ( (x != 1) && (y > 5)) || (z = 'abc'))
    email = 'abc@gmail.com';
```

I'm pretty sure this kind of XML structure is out there somewhere, could not find it.

I'm looking for the XML format and from that I can create an XSD for validation and C# code. If you know if somewhere that does one or more of this components that will be great.

Comment: You might be able to do something using the tools from the [`System.CodeDom`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt481474(v=vs.110).aspx) namespace.  It's what `xsd.exe` uses to do code generation.  See the tag [tag:codedom] for existing questions, e.g. [how to generate if condition block by CodeDOM or LinqExpression Dynamiclly?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3388610).

Answer (score 0):

See [RuleML](http://wiki.ruleml.org/index.php/RuleML_Home):

> RuleML (Rule Markup Language, which has also become a Rule Modeling
>   Language) is a unifying system of families of languages for Web rules
>   specified, in part, through schema languages (normatively, in Relax
>   NG) for Web documents and data originally developed for XML and later
>   transferred to other formats such as JSON.